# Android gallery scrolling issue (custom images)

Tags: android, gallery

I am new to android. I am using a custom gallery to show images and check boxes over images. Both have their own click listeners in adapter class getView() method. When I scroll the gallery, it doesn't scroll from images and check boxes. Instead it scrolls from free spaces between the image thumbs.

Comment: put some code here to detect whats the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved this issue in my scenario i have an image and a check box i have to implement click listener on image and check box i use "checkedChangedlistener" instead of Click listener on check box in get view method of adapter class

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
       holder = new ViewHolder();
       convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.icon, null);
       holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gCheckBox);
       holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
       {                            
          @Override
          public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
          {
             if(isChecked)
             {
             }
             else if(!isChecked)
             {
             }
          }
       });
    }
```

and after this i need Click listener for my image thumb so i use on item click listener of gallery in my activity.

```
    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) 
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(Conditions.this, TestExampleGUIActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);       
        }                               
    });
```

when item click event fires i perform my action which i want to perform on my image thumb. its working fine and gallery behavior is also fine

i am sorry! i am new to this forum so i have many issues to explain my problems i will improve this in future thanks to all of you